# Scala: Boolean check or simply return input parameter?

Tags: scala

I have a cache manager.
This has three sub classes:

`cacheOnClasspath, cacheOnFileSystem, NoCache`

All have a `save(stream:InputStream):InputStream=` method inherited from superclass. (We recreate the Stream for further processing after saving to cache, hence the returning `InputStream`)

Obviously, this is redundant in NoCache.
So I can either check cache type before calling `save.`

(pseudo code)

```
if(!cache.isNoCache){
     cache.save(stream)
}
```

or ....

I call `save`, and the `NoCache` implementation, just returns the stream. e.g.,

```
save(stream:InputStream):InputStream={
    stream
}
```

Am I correct that the second approach is faster than the first?

Comment: They are equally fast. But the second approach is better

Comment: because code is cleaner?

Comment: Yes. Because upstream application code should not have to be familiar with the specifics of implementation of your caches.